# <Android> Bluetooth Pairing Confirmation notification

Tags: android, bluetooth

We are developing an android application which connects to Bluetooth device using secure simple pairing. As expected, We observed that when ever the application connects to Bluetooth device using the android provided API's, a pairing confirmation dialog is generated for user confirmation.

On Nexus4, we observed that pairing notification is generated sometimes and the user needs to select the pairing notification to confirm pairing. Looking into the source code of Setting Application, specifically(BluetoothPairingRequest.java), there is a check for screen on/off to decide whether to generate a pairing dialog or notification. In our case, the screen is on, but it still generates a notification. Can someone please provide information on how this usecase(pairing notification) can be avoided.

Thanks in advance.

-Ashwin